# Dimension with two surrogate keys or two seperate dimensions?

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

im looking for some guidance for dimensional modeling.
I'm looking at some search data that is stored in a database in a star schema. There is one dimension for queries and one dimension for landing pages. Both dimensions have a surrogate key that are stored in the fact table as foreign keys.

The fact table has about 100 million rows and the dimensions each have about 100k rows.

As the joins of these tables are taking very long lately i'm wondering if it would be a good idea to combine the two dimensions into one so it only joins to one table. The two dimensions are M:N so the new dimension would be very huge.

Thanks!!

Comment: It depends on the workload. Are you aggregating? Filtering to specific rows? filtering on summary attributes in the dimensions? I assume the join columns are indexed.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a "right" answer for your question without knowing more about your data (like do you have more dimensions in your fact table? how many combinations of Queries and Landing pages do you have?), but few comments:

- You current design (for what I can understand from here) is not bad, you have a lot of data, you have to deal with it, but combine two dimensions with 100K elements to avoid a join doesn't seems right to me
- Try to optimize your queries, build indexes if you don't have them, parallelize your queries (if your db engine allows you to do so), try to avoid `like` in your where if possible, last resource think about more hardware or a different database engine.
- If you usually query using only one of these dimensions maybe you can think about aggregated tables to reduce the number of rows, you will use more space but your query will have a single join and a smaller fact table
- Can query be child of landing page? (i.e. stackoverflow.com is parent of queries like "Guru Meditation error message" and "stackcareers.com" is parent of "pool boy for datalake jobs") Of course you will end with the same query for multiple landing pages, you will need to assign different foreign keys in that case. But this different model can lead to a different solution, you will have only 1:M relationships and can build an aggregated table by landing page dimension, but this will require to change your queries to extract data. And again I don't know your data, maybe it will make more sense Queries parent of Landing Pages...

Again this are just my "thoughts" no solutions.